# Filter Data on Excel for one column based on values of other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if it is possible to filter data in one column based on the values of multiple other columns. For example this is what I would like to do. I have two columns: `Student_ID` and `Test_Score`. Each `Student_ID` has multiple `Test_Score`. I calculate the average and standard deviation of the `Test_Score` of each student, now I want to get rid of all the rows in which the `Test_Score` of each student is outside of one standard deviation away from the average. Here is an example:

```
Student_ID        Test_Score

1                 85

1                 90

1                 98

1                 71

1                 88
```

The average `Test_Score` for this student is: 86.4

The standard deviation for this student is: 9.86408

So from this I want to get rid of the third and fourth rows because they lie more than one standard deviation away from the average test score. I'm not too sure how to filter data like this in Excel, anyone have any idea how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard deviation for each Student-ID would be different and hence
I do not think you will be able to find a single formula which can handle this.

However, you can give a try writing some excel VBA code , which I feel should be able to achieve what you are expecting.

Comment: Right, I would like to do this for each unique Student_ID, find their unique Standard deviation and average and filter accordingly. I'll go ahead and try to write some VBA code for it.

Comment: Great!!  All the best for writing the VBA code. Feel free to write back your VBA code query in case if you get stuck anywhere.